# Trick to diagonalize symmetric matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I will write an exam on Quantum Mechanics soon. I was wondering whether there is any smart and fast way to determine the eigenvalues/eigenvectors of a symmetric 3x3 matrix other than by calculating the characteristic polynomial?

So I am only intersted in fast techniques that one can use by hand to get those things.

Comment: the characteristic polynomial is strategic to get its zeros a.k.a the eigenvalues

Comment: yes sure, but maybe there is anything better available for this particular type of matrices.

Comment: Create a characteristic polynomial and work backwards. And for $3 \times 3$ matrices, that's quick.  You could always use Maple if you don't want to do the calculations by hand.

Comment: or wolfram-alpha

Comment: yeah, but after that, i will get kicked out of the exam ;-)

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that once you have two eigenvectors, the third has to be orthogonal to each of the first two

Comment: For $2\times2$ real symmetric matrices there is [Mohr's circle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mohr's_circle), and every exercise to get fluent with that is well spent IMHO. Furthermore, the Wikipedia article contains an adaptation for $3$D, but first make sure that you can do the $2$D case confidently.

Comment: You can perform the QR algorithm by hand :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no special trick to find the eigenvalues/vectors of your matrix $A$ (instead of you just "see them" or more special cases of $A$) but if you want to diagonalize your matrix you can make benefit of the symmetry of the matrix when finding an transformation matrix $S$ with $\Delta = S A S^{-1} $

If $A$ is symmetric you know, that eigenvectors to different eigenvalues are ortthogonal, so it's most time very easy to find even an *orthonormal* basis of eigenvalues. The benefit for your calculation then is, that you don't have to find the inverse of your transformation matrix $S$ because it is given by its transposed matrix $S^T$

Now you are able to calculate the diagonal matrix $\Delta$ simply by $\Delta = S^T A S$